# Hide PDF-documents on server, but logged users can see them?

Tags: asp-classic

Say that I have a bunch of PDF documents on my web server uploaded to my web server by my user-system.
Say that they are top secret or very personal; could fx. be a paycheck, a customer contract or an invoice.

How do I hide the PDF-documents from the world, but make it visible and downloadable for users logged into my user-system?

Is this anyway possible?

I am using a fully dedicated Microsoft Web Server 2008 with SQL Server 2008 and IIS7. And I am server-scripting with ASP Classic.

*And yeah, I have been googling the scenario and I really can't find a specific example on how to do this. Which also lets me believe, that it is not possible :/*

Comment: How do users log in to your system?  Is this an intranet and are the users logged into a domain that the web server can recognize?

Comment: They log in like you would on a standard website where sessions checks if you are logged in and with what useraccount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you could use some ugly ASP code to pump contents of a PDF to the client but I'll not steer you that way when you have lovely modern server to play with.

Hopefully you haven't got any old ISAPI filters that require a classic pipeline.  Hence your application pool will be running the integrated pipeline.

I believe you can use the ASP.NET global.asax page filter incoming requests even for static content in the integrated pipeline.  The `AuthorizeRequest` might be a good place to put your code.

You will probably need to adjust your existing logon system (which probably depends on ASP Session) to also add an additional session cookie (one whose name and value you dictate) to the response for a logon request.

You would place the PDF files under some sub-folder in your application.  Your code in the `Global.asax` code-behind could then determine if the incoming request is for that sub-folder, if it is it could examine the cookies on the request to determine if your session cookie is present and that it has a valid value.

This has two advantages:-

1. It allows the existing static content handler to deliver the actual file to the client, which will be more efficient than trying to do it with code.
2. It gives your app small foot hold in the ASP.NET world.  From here you could consider delivering more features using ASP.NET instead.

Comment: I will definitely do more ASP.NET codes in the future, but it is a pretty big step going from ASP to ASP.NET. It would be like learning a whole new language :) So for now, that step is too big. --- I am already using cookies to define a unique key-string which is also defined in my database to uphold a long-time login when sessions expire. --- My IIS7 installation is a default installation which havent been touched, so I guess there should be no old ISAPI filters in the way :) --- Continued...

Comment: ... My plan is to put all the documents at the server's D: drive while the Windows installation is on the C: drive, would this be in the way of doing your approach? --- I have no idea what to do with the Global.asax and what to write in it, could you help with that? :)

Comment: Where you place the documents physically is not that important.  If you choose not to place them under the same physical folder of your app then you can add a Virtual Folder to the website so that users can retrieve them.

Comment: Doing a lot in ASP.NET may be a big step but this sounds like an opportunity to dip a toe in without much cost and delivers a big benefit over traditional solutions to your requirement.  The other approaches available in ASP alone are IMO compromised.  Now is the time to pick up an ASP.NET book and have stab.  Don't forget that if you have a quick go and fail you can always post to SO on the ASP.NET tag and get help.  With the ASP.NET tag being far more active the help will come more quickly too.

Answer (score 0):

Place them in a folder above the domain folder.

Comment: How does this make the files accessible to authenticated users but not to others.

Comment: You can retrieve physical file paths

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is to be able to stream files to a browser.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276488

The one problem you may run in to by doing this is the limit of your server's memory. ASP loads the entire file in to memory before it sends it. So if you're doing this with very large files, you might run in to problems.

Comment: How large would the files be, if I should run into these problems? :)

Comment: @FoxInSocks:  Not if you turn buffering off, but the client side end is no longer able to give good progress information when you do that.